# Ansible issue with line file module

Tags: python, ansible, yaml

**I have sample file called clado.txt with following content.**

```
[server]

[backend]

[frontend]
```

**I am trying  to inset a line "apache1" under the [server] section.**

```
[server]
apache1

[backend]

[frontend]
```

**My playbook**

```
---
- hosts: aws
  become: yes
  remote_user: ec2-user
  tasks:
  - name: editing /home/ec2-user/clado.txt.
    lineinfile: 
      dest: /home/ec2-user/clado.txt
      insertafter: "[server]"
      line: "apche1"
```

**But I am not getting my desired output.**

```
[server]

[backend]

[frontend]
apche1
```

How can I place the word "apache1" under [server]

Comment: This looks like an INI file you're creating. I'm not sure if it works, but checkout http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/ini_file_module.html, this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `insertafter` is a regular expression, so you need to escape brackets with backslashes.

```
insertafter: "\\[server\\]"
```

In a vast majority of cases, you should use Ansible [`template` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/template_module.html) and specify the desired contents, instead of relying on the current state of the target machine.

Comment: You need two backslashes with double-quote or one with a single-quote -- I mixed them up.